# How to use a typing which provides an external module as global?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

We have a large TS application mostly written way before 2.0. We are not using modules, but only the `outfile` option. We've been using `global` typings so far, but now some of the typings provided by `typings` are not supporting global usage (as far as I understand).

For example I'm now trying to use the typings for `markdown-it`, which doesn't expose anythings to the global namespace, hence the compiler doesn't find the `markdownit` function.

I'm quite confused about how we should use these kind of typings in these circumstances, any hints would be appreciated.

Example code:

```
// test.ts
var result = markdownit().render("*some markdown*"); <-- `markdownit` not found
```

When I try to `import` it, it gives error of course, because I'm not using modules. So I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really want to use markdown-it as global variable `markdownit`, you can declare it in your own file that [augments global scope](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules) (this feature is new in 2.0).

Create a file `markdown-it-global.d.ts`

```
declare module 'markdown-it-global' {

    import * as MarkdownIt from 'markdown-it';

    global {
        var markdownit: typeof MarkdownIt;
    }

}
```

This declares an ambient module that augments global scope - if you include `markdown-it-global.d.ts` together with all other typecsript source files and declarations like `typing/index.d.ts`, it will make global variable `markdownit` available everywhere.

The `import` inside it uses markdown-it typings that declare a module, but it will be used for typechecking only, it will not have any effect on generated javascript code and will not actually require it to use modules.

Comment: I really want to use it like this because I have no other choice. We have thousands of lines written without using modules, it's a hard work to transform it  which we can't afford. On a new project I would definitely go with modules. Thank you for the answer, will try tomorrow.